# do arithmetic on query result

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Can I do arithmetic on query results? My query returns two rows.

```
POSITION_ID   DEAL_ID   OFFSET  CURRENT SWAP   SWAP
20756839      5397396     0      22657         27880
20756839      6154345     1      22657         0
```

Two different deals have taken place for the same position. One having offset 1 and the other 0.
Now, what I want to implement is :
I need to check if the OFFSET is 0,first I should not print that row on output and second, join the DEAL_ID of this row with another table having same foreign key and get the CLOSED-SWAP from that table. Finally, I subtract the swap of DEAL_ID 5397396,(HAVING OFFSET 0, above) from the CLOSED_SWAP I get from another table by joining DEAL_IDs.

This is the other table to get the value of CLOSED_SWAP

```
TABLE CLOSE_POSITION_DETAIL_ID
{
   DEAL_ID,
   closed_swap,
   xxx etc
}
```

for example, the swap value of above deal is  22657 - closed_swap I get from another table.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you want the results to be?  Please edit your question.

Comment: Huh?  Please show expected output, and "other table," etc.  Not at all clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use group by and count distinct numbers of offset.
The sample is below:

```
    select sum(decode(at.did, 11 , -at.swap, at.swap)) Diff from
    (
    select pid , count(distinct offset) from result
    where did in (12, 11)
    group by pid 
    having count(distinct offset)  = 2 ) Gr
    join anotherTable  At
    on AT.did in (11, 12)
```

Assuming your structure like:

```
create table result 
(PID number,
 DID number,
 OFFSET number);

 create table anotherTable
 (did number,
  swap number);

 insert into anotherTable values
 (12, 10);

  insert into anotherTable values
 (11, 5);

 insert into result values(
 1, 11,  0);

  insert into result values(
 1, 12, 1);
```

It's very simplified sample as the question is not really clear.

Comment: @user1596226 It's not really clearer after your edit.  Maybe write expected result too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, how to make the query work when we get 1000 records from result and need to check if position ids are pair - one offset 0 and the other 1, then calculate the sum ?

Comment: add group by your ids.

Comment: what about these lines ? where did in (12, 11)

Comment: it's hardcoded from your previous version of question... In your current sample you should get it by additional join to main result using POSITION_ID.